# No Route Matches for Image in Assets/Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline

I have an image that I just added to /assets/images. When I reference it in my application with this code:

```
<%= image_tag("profilewall.png", alt: "The Team", :id => "aboutusright") %>
```

I get a broken image in the web browser and this in the server:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/profilewall.png"):

I read the entire Asset Pipeline description in the guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and saw some things that I thought would fix it but none did. I tried to run

> rake assets:precompile

but that didn't make it work. I also tried to change the

> config.assets.compress = false

line in development.rb and none of these things have worked. When I change the image name to other images in the assets/images folder it works just fine. I can't figure it out. I assume I am missing something rather remedial about the asset pipeline but at this point I have tried everything I can think of and nothing is working. I have restarted the server, restarted both terminal and textmate but no luck. This broken image is killing me! Also, the image is not inheriting the class that I tell it to take (even when I aim it at another image that works). So it isn't displaying with some images and it isn't recognizing its class when it works with other images.

It has been quite the roadblock today. Any help would be appreciated. A quick little explanation of when these images get compiled/when I need to restart stuff would help also. This image will be a static image on the home page. Is this the best place to put it? I read in the guides that the "public" folder might be a better spot because then it will be cached.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I just went into /public/assets and dropped the file in there and it worked like a charm. Can someone explain to me why this is the case with the asset pipeline? I am baffled (but grateful it is working).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798646/what-are-the-best-practices-when-organizing-assets-in-rails-asset-pipeline -- The answer there may solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you are mixing ruby 1.9.3 hash syntax with 1.8 syntax in the method call.

Change the helper to:

```
<%= image_tag("profilewall.png", :alt => "The Team", :id => "aboutusright") %>
```

and if that does not work edit the question and I'll look into it some more.

(If this is an upgraded app, check that all the config settings match those in the last section of the pipeline guide.)

Edit:

I assume this in development mode?

If the file is served when you move it to public/assets/images then that means you have a config option set incorrectly. Under normal (default) circumstances in dev mode if there is no static asset to serve the request gets passed to Sprockets. I can see from this that Sprockets is not processing the request, so must be 'off'.

This would be the `config.assets.compile`, and it is true by default (for development) and set to false in production, assuming that assets are precompiled.

My guess is that this is set to false in application.rb or development.rb. Check that all your setting match those in the last section of the pipeline guide, delete all the files in `public/assets` and in `tmp/cache/assets/`, restart your server and it *should* work.

Comment: Richard, I was messing around with both to see if it made a difference. It didn't make a difference on the app that I was using even when I mixed the syntaxes when I used one of the images that worked.

Comment: I tried your revised recommendation Richard. It stopped working at that point. I appreciate all your help so far. I think I am missing some critical information about Sprockets, precompiling and the asset pipeline. I will do some more homework so I understand it better and then add a follow up. Thanks for your efforts to help.

Comment: I don't remember if I did or not. I haven't looked at this for a long time. If you add your issue though and the relevant code I could take a look at it to see if I could help.